# Error compiling PyGraphviz 1.2 on OSX Mavericks with Xcode 5

Tags: python, xcode, macos

G'day everyone,

I am trying to install PyGraphviz 1.2 on OSX Mavericks. I have just upgraded from Mountain Lion and now have Xcode 5.0.1 installed with Command Line Tools. I have downloaded the PyGraphviz source package, unpacked it and ran `sudo python setup.py install`.

I am getting the following error message (there is some output prior to this, including several warnings):

```
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o -L/usr/local/lib/graphviz -L/usr/local/lib/graphviz -lcgraph -lcdt -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so
ld: library not found for -lcgraph
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Also, the first two lines of output are:

```
library_path=/usr/local/lib/graphviz
include_path=/usr/local/include/graphviz
```

which leads me to believe that compiler knows where to look for libraries.

What could be the problem? Just to make things clear: for technical reasons I have to use Apple's version of Python 2.7 and everything works fine on my other machine with OSX Lion and Xcode 4... (not sure what the exact version is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a same error and resolved it by installing command line tools for XCode. Assuming you upgraded your XCode to 5.0.1, you can install command line tools by typing "xcode-select --install" to terminal and it will prompt you to install command line tools.

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked like a charm. I do not understand why Xcode claimed it had Command Line Tools installed when in fact it didn't. I did not see this option in Preferences/Downloads and in Preferences/Locations it looked like everything was there. Besides, I had Command Line Tools installed with the previous version of Xcode. Maybe they are incompatible and Xcode 5.0.1 is unaware of this...